# nodejs path.resolve unix path (posix format) in windows prepends duplicated driver name?

Tags: node.js, path

My dir is at `H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src` (using windows + nodejs)

When I try to **`path.resolve(__dirname, 'aa')`**

- *see update below -- the way I get `__dirname` (in esm) has some problem*

Im expecting to get: `H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa` or `H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src/aa`

But what I get is: `H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa`
-- see that **"prepends duplicated driver name" in `H:\H:\`**?

To fix it I have to `path.resolve(__dirname.substring(1), 'aa')`.

So, 
Why I have to do that extra step (feels unsafe)? 
Why `path.resolve(__dirname, 'aa')` cant just simply do its job? Shouldnt it recognize the difference between unix & windows system path automatically?

eg:

```
printlc(import.meta.url);                                                                 // file:///H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src/WordLemmatizerService.ts
printlc(__dirname);                                                                       // /H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src
printlc('---');                                                                           // ---
printlc(path.resolve(__dirname));                                                         // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc(path.normalize(__dirname));                                                       // \H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc(path.resolve(__dirname.substring(1)));                                            // H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc(path.normalize(__dirname).substring(1));                                          // H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc('---');                                                                           // ---
printlc(path.resolve(__dirname, 'aa')); // wrong                                          // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
printlc(path.resolve(path.normalize(__dirname), 'aa')); // wrong                          // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
printlc(path.resolve(__dirname.substring(1), 'aa')); // correct                           // H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
printlc(path.resolve(path.normalize(__dirname).substring(1), 'aa')); // correct           // H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
printlc('---');                                                                           // ---
printlc(path.posix.resolve(__dirname));                                                   // /H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src
printlc(path.posix.normalize(__dirname));                                                 // /H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src
printlc(path.win32.resolve(__dirname));                                                   // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc(path.win32.normalize(__dirname));                                                 // \H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src
printlc('---');                                                                           // ---
printlc(path.posix.resolve(__dirname, 'aa')); // wrong?                                   // /H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src/aa
printlc(path.posix.resolve(path.posix.normalize(__dirname), 'aa')); // wrong?             // /H:/Book/debug/TxbookHlstDebug/libNt/hlst-buildhtml-foredit/js/main/src/aa
printlc(path.win32.resolve(__dirname, 'aa')); // wrong                                    // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
printlc(path.win32.resolve(path.win32.normalize(__dirname), 'aa')); // wrong              // H:\H:\Book\debug\TxbookHlstDebug\libNt\hlst-buildhtml-foredit\js\main\src\aa
```

- (`printlc` <=> `console.log`)

---

***Update***

- The problem was that Im using esm, not commonjs.

  if I directly refer to `__dirname`, error will show
  `Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope`

  so my `__dirname` in my ex was coming from

  ```
  const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
  const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
  ```

  and that **makes the extra `/`** (as my output above shown).
- The better way to do it & solves the problem is:

  ```
  const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
  const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
  ```

Comment: What's your windows and nodejs version? I don't see this problem in my machine (windows 10, node v18.12.1)

Comment: @YuchengZhou actually, not the version problem. its the way I get `__dirname` (in esm) has some problem. (see updated post)